# How do i check how long a hover lasts?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a UI Image GameObject and i want to make it so that if you hover over it for a second it zooms but if at any point the cursor leaves the GameObject stays the same size. The way i wanted to do it was to check for first Pointer enter with OnPointerEnter and after a second elapses to check again if the cursor is on the Image but i had no luck with trying to find a way of checking if mouse is over the Image. Another thing i tried to find was if there is any way to delay OnPointerEnter by one second but most of the stuff i found made it delayed but if i moved my cursor away from the Image it would still zoom after a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flag when **PointerEtner** and **PointerExit**, so that you can get the cursor isHovered by that flag.

```
public bool isHovered = false;

public void DoWhenHover()
{
    isHovered = true;
    StartCoroutine(DelayZoom());   
}

IEnumerator DelayZoom()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    print("Zoom the image");
}

public void DoWhenExit()
{
    isHovered = false;
    StartCoroutine(DelayRecover());
}

IEnumerator DelayRecover()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    print("Reset the image");
}
```

[image]